# Show instant current location

Tags: android, google-maps

I have some issues related to map loading. It blinks 2-3 time till I got current location instead of this I want to load map directly on my current location whenever application open. Please let me know if there are any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to use google maps then the code is:

```
        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude
                + "," +
                longitude);

        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(mapIntent);
```